# Is total angular momentum conserved in particle interaction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws

Imagine that two electrons interact by exchanging a virtual photon.

I know that the total energy and linear momentum of the two electrons is conserved by the interaction.

Is the total (orbital) angular momentum of the electrons conserved as well?

If the photon transfers energy and momentum between the electrons does it also transfer angular momentum between them?

Comment: Total angular momentum is conserved, but orbital angular momentum is not.

Comment: According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_angular_momentum_of_light, they must be able to transfer orbital angular momentum too.